# SQL : How to search column name in DB (within set of tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If my database has large set of tables then -

Is there any way / query which will search - which table contains particular column name ?

Eg. I want to know the name of table which contains column `par_token`.

How can I achieve this? - I am using SQL Management Studio 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sys` objects:

```sql
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = N'par_token';
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.  The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are (relatively) standard views available across databases.  And, you don't need any joins:

```
select c.*
from information_schema.columns c
where c.column_name = 'par_token';
```